# Call signatures in typescript with 'this'

Tags: typescript

Attempting to understand the 'call signatures' section of the typescript handbook, I tried to write some experimental code where the `hello` function is passed into `doSomething`.

Unfortunately, that yields the error listed below, which leaves me baffled.  Any light would be appreciated.

I'm aware I could just follow `fn hello` with `hello.description = 35` and all would be fine, but why is it that attempting to use `this`, as in `this.description = '35'`) throws such an big error, and how could it be fixed?

```
type DescribableFunction = {
  (someArg: number): boolean; 
  description: string;
};

function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction) {
  console.log(fn.description + " returned " + fn(6));
}

type X = {
  description: string
}

function hello(this: X, num: number): boolean {
  this.description = '35';
  return true;
}

doSomething(hello)
```

Results - a red squiggly line under the `hello` argument and:

```
Argument of type '(this: X, num: number) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DescribableFunction'.

Property 'description' is missing in type '(this: X, num: number) => boolean' but required in type 'DescribableFunction'.
```

Answer (score 2):

The error basically tells you what's wrong:

- You specify that `DescribableFunction`s have a `.description` field
- `hello` is a regular function that does not have that field. You're only adding it *after* (well, during) the call to `hello` *(and that's assuming you're calling `hello` with `this` set to `hello`, which you don't. see end of this answer)*

TypeScript is smart enough that adding `hello.description = 'placeholder';` (outside `hello`) should do the trick:

```js
type DescribableFunction = {
    (someArg: number): boolean;
    description: string;
};

function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction) {
    console.log(fn.description + " returned " + fn(6));
}

type X = {
    description: string
}

function hello(this: X, num: number): boolean {
    this.description = '35';
    return true;
}

hello.description = 'hi';

doSomething(hello)
```

Also mind that doing `fn(6)` doesn't actually call `fn` with `this` being set to `fn`. You might have the wrong idea there. Besides, if you have objects with fields, it's better to use objects or classes.